# How to call nifi processor using a python script along with the values comming in attributes

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to invoke my nifi pipeline from command line .using python script .Is there anyway to do that .

i get few data from generateflowfile as attributes i need same attributes from python script is there any way to do that

Comment: start your nifi flow with ListenHTTP processor and from python call this endpoint and pass everything you need in body (goes to file content) and headers (goes to file attributes)

Comment: Take a look at the Nifi Rest Api, you can also leverage the Rest endpoints for things like you have mentioned https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html